# Suppose that A is a countable set. Show that the set B is also countable if there is an onto function f from A to B.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is my logic correct/accepted?

1. Let A be a countable set.
2. Let f:A->B, surjective.
3. $\exists$g:A->N, bijective. Using definition from 1.
4. $\exists$h:N->B, surjective.
5. $\therefore$B is countable by definition using 4.

Am I allowed to assume #4? Does anything need to be cleared up?

Comment: You are right, but to make it complete you have to say one or two words on how you construct your function $h$ (as you ask about the validity you may not be aware of how this is done). But it is not that difficult, it is just the composition $g$ followed by $h$, or $h \circ g$ (if you have the characterisation at hand that a set is at most countable iff there exists a surjection from $\mathbb N$ onto that set, which I assume as you write "using definition 4").

Comment: "Countable" does not mean that there is a bijection to $\Bbb N$; that would be *countably infinie*.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't quite right - in addition to Stefan's comment re: defining $h$ explicitly, it seems you are using two different definitions of countability: "there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$" (in 4), and "there is a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$" (in 3). These aren't the same - in particular, the latter doesn't apply to finite sets! (And I think the most common definition is "there is an *injection into* $\mathbb{N}$," which is equivalent to "there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$, but is strictly speaking a different definition.)

You need to show how you can get the map you want using *one* definition of countability.